# Error using fprintf Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs (regarding "solve" and "fprintf")

Tags: matlab, printf

The following is our code:

```
syms M_e
solve('9.5=0.58*(((1+(0.155*M_e^2))^3.73)/M_e',M_e);
fprintf('text %d .\n',M_e);
```

When I run it, we get the following error:

```
>> SM_Projekt_29

ans =

3.5712628547590099257134566797414

Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'sym' inputs.


Error in SM_Projekt_29 (line 34)
fprintf('text %d .\n',M_e);
```

How can I resolve this error? Does the error occur because it doesn't continue to calculate with the solved value `M_e`? How can I fix that?

Comment: It's a fairly straightforward error, it tells you you cannot use symbolics in `fprintf`. Try converting your result to a string or character array an use that as input for `fprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `fprintf` on a `sym` variable, which isn't allowed.  `fprintf` is for numbers (single values, matrices, vectors), or character arrays / strings.  Try converting your `sym` type variable to `double`, then display it.  Also, change the specifier to `%f`, not `%d`, as I highly suspect your answer will be floating-point.

In addition, you **haven't assigned the output of `solve` to anything**.  Make sure you do that before you run your code:

```
syms M_e;
val = solve('9.5=0.58*(((1+(0.155*M_e^2))^3.73)/M_e)',M_e); %// Change
fprintf('text %f .\n',double(val)); %// Change
```

Running your corrected code, I get this:

```
val =

    3.5713
```

If you want to display more significant digits, try using `format long g;` before displaying the answer:

```
>> format long g;
>> val

val =

          3.57126285475901
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we have the following error when we use your suggestion: 

Error using symengine (line 58)
DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into a double array.
If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use VPA.

Error in sym/double (line 523)
        Xstr = mupadmex('symobj::double', S.s, 0);

Error in SM_Projekt_29 (line 34)
fprintf('Die Machzahl beträgt %f .\n',double(M_e))

Comment: @MatinShah - You need to check my edits.  I get an answer.  Basically, you were printing out the wrong variable.

Comment: Ghe, I didn't know MATLAB in other languages also translated the error messages. Makes things even less understandable :)

Comment: @A.Visser - hahaha, yup.

Comment: @MatinShah - No problem.  Please consider accepting my answer if you are satisfied.  That can be done by clicking on the checkmark icon, at the top of my post to the left below the left and right arrow buttons.  Good luck!

Comment: @rayryeng, isn't 3 "thank you"s enough? Do you need to have the answer accepted too...? Geez =P

Comment: @StewieGriffin - IT IS NEVER ENOUGH!  BTW thanks for the upvote :D

Comment: @A.Visser - Have you come by to visit us in the MATLAB chat room? :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab-and-octave - stop by if you have time! We're there often.